# How to call the jQuery nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call the nested function is not working 
Here is what I tried [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/LaUaE/)

Script:

```
(function( $ ){
      $.fn.investPage = function() {    
            function setupFCConfig(){
                $('.nestedFunction').click(function(){
                    alert('setupFCConfig func()');
                });
            }
            $(".edit").on('click', function(){
                alert('edit click func()');
            }); 
            $(".cancel").on('click', function(){        
                alert('cancel click func()');   
            }); 
            $(".checkout").click(function(){        
                alert('checkout click func()');
            });
      };
})( jQuery );

$.fn.investPage();
$.fn.investPage.setupFCConfig();
```

Comment: You've misspelled `click` as `clicl` in `setupFCConfig()`

Comment: There is a typo, `clicl` should be `click`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setupFCConfig()` is NOT a property of the $.fn.investPage object so it can't be called like this:

```
 $.fn.investPage.setupFCConfig();
```

It is a local function that is not available outside the scope in which it is declared.  If you want it available from an outside scope, then you need to assign it to be a property of some object that is available in that outside scope.

For example, you could change the definition of that function to be like this:

```
(function( $ ){
      $.fn.investPage = function() {    
            $(".edit").on('click', function(){
                alert('edit click func()');
            }); 
            $(".cancel").on('click', function(){        
                alert('cancel click func()');   
            }); 
            $(".checkout").click(function(){        
                alert('checkout click func()');
            });

      };
      $.fn.investPage.setupFCConfig = function (){
           $('.nestedFunction').click(function(){
               alert('setupFCConfig func()');
           });
      }

})( jQuery );

$.fn.investPage();
$.fn.investPage.setupFCConfig();
```

FYI, you also need to fix the misspelling of `.click`.

Answer (score 3):

you are using the wrong scope for the function

```
(function( $ ){
      $.fn.investPage = function() {    
            $(".edit").on('click', function(){
                alert('edit click func()');
            }); 
            $(".cancel").on('click', function(){        
                alert('cancel click func()');   
            }); 
            $(".checkout").click(function(){        
                alert('checkout click func()');
            });
      };
      $.fn.investPage.setupFCConfig = function(){
          $('.nestedFunction').click(function(){
              alert('setupFCConfig func()');
          });
      };
})( jQuery );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaUaE/4/)

or

```
(function( $ ){
      $.fn.investPage = function() {
          this.setupFCConfig = function(){
              $('.nestedFunction').click(function(){
                  alert('setupFCConfig func()');
              });
          };          
            $(".edit").on('click', function(){
                alert('edit click func()');
            }); 
            $(".cancel").on('click', function(){        
                alert('cancel click func()');   
            }); 
            $(".checkout").click(function(){        
                alert('checkout click func()');
            });
          return this;
      };
})( jQuery );

var page = $.fn.investPage();
page.setupFCConfig();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaUaE/6/)

The second returns the `investPage` object where you can than access the function from the object variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use it this way [jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/LaUaE/7/)
In the scope of `$.fn.investPage` the `this` is not the `$.fn.investPage` object. So your object does not *know* the function `setupFCConfig()`.

But you can use:

```
$.fn.investPage.setupFCConfig = function(){
    $('.nestedFunction').click(function(){
            alert('setupFCConfig func()');
    });
};
```

to achive your goal.

Answer (score 2):

you can make an object and use it for namespace like below too

```
    investPage = {
        init: function () {
            $(".edit").on('click', function(){
                alert('edit click func()');
            }); 
            $(".cancel").on('click', function(){        
                alert('cancel click func()');   
            }); 
            $(".checkout").click(function(){        
                alert('checkout click func()');
            });
            }, 
        setupFCConfig:  function (){
           $('.nestedFunction').click(function(){
                    alert('setupFCConfig func()');
           });
        }
    }


investPage.init();
investPage.setupFCConfig();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LaUaE/12/

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to :

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.investPage = function() {    
      this.setupFCConfig: function (){
            $('.nestedFunction').click(function(){
                alert('setupFCConfig func()');
            });
        };
        $(".edit").on('click', function(){
            alert('edit click func()');
        }); 
        $(".cancel").on('click', function(){        
            alert('cancel click func()');   
        }); 
        $(".checkout").click(function(){        
            alert('checkout click func()');
        });
  };
})( jQuery );

var instance = $.fn.investPage();
instance.setupFCConfig();
```

Comment: this will not work as you do not have an instance of `investPage`, to access the setupFCConfig method like you have at the bottom you would have to change it to be a property of investPage, ie: `$.fn.investPage.setupFCConfig = function`